# Changing Payload based on Response body

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have a working HTTP POST Request in Angular 7 with HttpClient as below which is returning details of a user profile:

```
const request {
  firstName: this.firstName,
  lastName: this.lastName,
  city: "Dallas"
}

this.http.post("URL Path", request).subscribe(response => console.log(response);
```

My question is, is it possible to change the value of the payload based on the response body? For example, if the city field is returned blank then change it's value as per below:

```
this.http.post("URL Path", request).subscribe(response => {
     if (response.toString().includes("Null"){
         request.city = "Detroit"
         //Resubmit POST request
     }
```

Comment: Is there a part of your code that isn't working? Why would you want to resubmit?

Comment: It is working, but I want to be able to change a value in the payload based on a Null value in the response body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might give `iif()` a shot.

```js
// will issue another request when iif condition is true
this.http.post('URL Path', request).pipe(
  map(response => response.toString()),
  mergeMap(response => iif(() => response.includes('null'),
    this.http.post('URL Path', { request.firstName, request.lastName, 'Detroit' }),
    of(response)
  ))  
);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `switchMap` operator for this use case.

```
const request = {
  firstName: this.firstName,
  lastName: this.lastName,
  city: 'Dallas'
};

this.http.post(url, request).pipe(
  switchMap(response => {
    return response.toString().includes('null')
      ? this.http.post(url, {...request, city: 'Detroit'})
      : of(response);
  })
).subscribe(console.log);
```